# copy data from one table to another partitioning table

Tags: hive, hiveql, partitioning, hive-partitions

```
%hive
INSERT INTO NEWPARTITIONING partition(year(L_SHIPDATE)) select * from LINEITEM;
```

I want to copy the data from line item to the partitioning table `NEWPARTITIONING` but I got the following error:

> line 1:54 cannot recognize input near ')' 'select' '*' in statement.

Don't understand why this error occurs. Can anyone give me some ideas

Comment: I am not sure if you can pass functions in partition clause. Why dont you create a new column in `LINEITEM` table(or create a view  on off of ) and try this `INSERT INTO NEWPARTITIONING partition(yyyy_L_shipdt)) select * from LINEITEM;`  In case dynamic partitioning, you need to ensure last column in source should match to the partitiong.

Answer (score 1):

Hive supports **DYNAMIC** or **STATIC** partition loading.

Partition specification allows only column name or column list (for **dynamic partition load**), if you need function, then calculate it in the select, see example below:

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;

insert into table NEWPARTITIONING partition (partition_column)
select i.col1,
       ...
       i.colN,
       year(L_SHIPDATE) as partition_column --Partition should be the last in column list
  from LINEITEM i
```

Or you can specify **static** partition in the form `partition(partition_column='value')`, in this case you do not need to select partition expression:

```
insert into table NEWPARTITIONING partition (partition_column='2020-01-01')
select i.col1,
       ...
       i.colN
  from LINEITEM i 
 where year(L_SHIPDATE)  = '2020-01-01'
```

In both cases - STATIC and DYNAMIC, Hive does not support functions in partition specification. Functions can be calculated in the query (dynamic load) or calculated in a wrapper shell and passed as a parameter to the script (for static partition).