# Can I use regular expression in PARTITION BY?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hiveql, create-table, hive-partitions

```
  (
      ResponseRgBasketId          STRING,
      RawStandardisedLoadDateTime TIMESTAMP,
      InfoMartLoadDateTime        TIMESTAMP,
      Operaame               STRING,
      RequestTimestamp            TIMESTAMP,
      RequestSiteId               STRING,
      RequestSalePointId          STRING,
      RequestdTypeId       STRING,
      RequeetValue          DECIMAL(10,2),
      ResponsegTimestamp TIMESTAMP,
      RequessageId            STRING,
      RequestBasketId             STRING,
      ResponsesageId           STRING,
      RequestTransmitAttempt      INT,
      ResponseCode                STRING,
      RequestasketItems    INT,
      ResponseFinancialTimestamp  TIMESTAMP,
      RequeketJsonString     STRING,
      LoyaltyId                   STRING
  )
  USING DELTA
  PARTITIONED BY (RequestTimestamp)
  TBLPROPERTIES
  (
      delta.deletedFileRetentionDuration = "interval 1 seconds",
      delta.autoOptimize.optimizeWrite = true
  )
```

It has been partitioned by `RequestTimestamp`(2020-12-12T07:39:35.000+0000
), but it has the format as below. Could I change the format to different format to something like `2020-12-34` in partition by?

[image]

Comment: Probably not possible. Alternately, if you pass `substring(RequestTimestamp,1,10)` to the last column into the table, i think it should be fine and use `2020-12-34` to create partition.

Comment: @leftjoin how can that partition be dynamic and based on a formula? Do you have any idea?

Comment: @KoushikRoy Sure. the only way is to recreate table and reload using substring(RequestTimestamp,1,10). BTW what is a strange date 2020-12-34?  I guess this is very important message. It really was  2020-12-34 but I slept it over it because 2020-12-31 celebrated  NewYear too much

Comment: LOL, hey, its `2020`, anything can happen. Jokes aside, i understand your point of reloading. I was thinking if this is a table thats loaded from some transactional source/sensor directly. And if we can create a partition name on the fly using some formula.

Comment: Answered with example.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No regexp or other transformation is possible in PARTITIONED BY.
The only solution is to apply substr(timestamp, 1, 10) during/before load.
See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64171676/2700344

Long answer:

No regexp is possible in PARTITIONED BY. No functions are allowed in table DDL, only type can be specified. Type in column specification works as constraint and at the same time can cause implicit type conversion. For example if you are loading strings into dates, it will be casted implicitly if possible and loaded into null **default** partition if not possible to cast. Also if you are loading BIGINT, it will be silently truncated to INT, as a result you will see corrupted data and duplicates.

**Does the same implicit cast work with partitioned by?** Let,s see:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_partition;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_partition (Id   int)
    partitioned by (dt date) --Hope timestamp will be truncated to DATE
;

set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;

insert overwrite table test_partition partition(dt)
select 1 as id, current_timestamp as dt;

show partitions test_partition;
```

Result (We expect timestamp truncated to DATE...):

```
dt=2021-03-24 10%3A19%3A19.985
```

No, it does not work. Tested the same with varchar(10) column with strings like yours.
See short answer.