# Error inserting data into Hive partitioned table

Tags: hive, hiveql, database-partitioning

I'm trying to insert data into a Hive table with partition, the partition condition is yesterday's date in yyyyMMdd format, and I want to do that dynamically so I'm generating it using a query. The date query works fine in my other select statement, however when inserting it's throwing an error like this:

[Error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFO8N.png)

Could you guys help me? Thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: here is my statement: INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE dwh_vts.staging_f_vts_sale_revenue PARTITION(date=DATE_FORMAT(date_sub(CURRENT_DATE,1),'yyyyMMdd')) VALUES ('N350','10','4500000.000000'),('T280','21','3760000.000000');

Comment: Hive does not support functions in partition specification, read this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/64171676/2700344

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view to load data or tweak your sql to do it. Make sure you have this date column as last column and partitioned by this column in table.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE dwh_vts.staging_f_vts_sale_revenue PARTITION(`date`) 
SELECT 'N350','10','4500000.000000',DATE_FORMAT(date_sub(CURRENT_DATE,1),'yyyyMMdd')
union
SELECT 'T280','21','3760000.000000',,DATE_FORMAT(date_sub(CURRENT_DATE,1),'yyyyMMdd')
```

Or you can put above SQL into a view and then insert overwrite from the view.